Azure Data Factory ForEach inner activity error message
In ADF, how do you get the actual error message of the failed activity inside the ForEach, instead of the msg "Activity failed because an inner activity failed".
I want to get the actual error message when run the execute pipeline activity on the pipeline that has a foreach activity, when failed.

Unfortunately, based on my understanding any activity that fails within the for each or until or switch activity error messages do not populate at the pipeline level directly.
In order for you to get that, you would have to define a variable,
map the variable with the error message within the for each activity
and use a fail activity outside of the foreach with the fail message as the variable
